# MPAndroidChart how to add info views to the axises?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndroidChart and i trying add info views (Oct 23 /1,250) to top and to end to the highLight lines as on the picture. I can add a marker but only one to the center (cross circle) but i don't how to add views to the lines. Does any one know how can i do it?

---

[image]

Comment: do you want the marker to show both x and y values?

Comment: On to of the Y axes and to end of X axes as on the picture. This lib supports only one marker, so i guess that has to be another way to do this